# If $P^{-1}BPA=AP^{-1}BP$ then $AB=BA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $ A,B\in \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{C})$ be two diagonalizable matrices and $D:=P^{-1}BP$ be a diagonal matrix such that $AD=DA$.

Can we say that $AB=BA$?

Comment: Suppose the 2 eigenvalues are distinct and let $A=D$. Then $AB=BA$ implies $B$ must be diagonal which is a contradiciton

Comment: @user What exactly is contradicted? Why is $B$ note allowed to be diagonal?

Comment: @BenGrossmann your question to me: "why is B not allowed to be diagonal" is a non-sequitor. Why did you write this?  To make this clear: my use of 'must be diagonal' $\to$ contradiction is because the conjugacy class of $D$ contains a lot more than 2 matrices and OP is trying to reason about commuting with an entire conjugacy class based on commuting with one representative.  But it seems you recognize this and basically wrote my comment as an answer (though I suggested setting $A:= D$ instead of setting $A$ equal to some other diagonal matrix as you've done; same thing).

Comment: @user8675309 The question is very much a sequitur. What you wrote doesn't seem like a contradiction to me either. $B$ being diagonal is something that doesn't necessarily follow from the assumptions. It is something that isn't always true. But it is not a contradiction. And even if your comment is correct (I and Ben might be wrong here, after all), asking why a claim of yours is true is never a non-sequitur. How could it be?

Comment: @user I asked my question because it wasn't clear what you were saying. When people say "X is a contradiction", they either mean that X is inherently contradictory or that X, in and of itself, contradicts another conclusion reached from the premise. It would have made more sense (to me at least) if you had instead something like "which **leads to** a contradiction".

Comment: I originally thought that you meant that "$B$ is diagonal" is the contradiction". I now suspect that your mindset here is that the statement "$AB = BA$ implies $B$ must be diagonal" contradicts the following reformulation of the question statement: "if $AD = DA$, then $AB = BA$ holds for **all** matrices of similar to $D$ (not just the diagonal ones)". If that's the case then I see where you're coming from, but I think it's still a stretch to call "$AB = BA$ implies $B$ must be diagonal" a contradiction of the statement as given (because of the necessary reformulation).

Comment: @BenGrossmann I am fine with your reformulation.  There is a big difference between writing *"= implies  **can** be diagonal which is a contradiction"* and *"= implies  **must** be diagonal which is a contradiction"*.  I only wrote the latter but your comment "why is B not allowed to be diagonal" was re: the former. That's why I thought your question was a non-sequitor. Yet another formulation of OP's question is: if $A\in GL_n$ commutes with a diagonal matrix $D$ is the automorphism given by conjugation by $A$ on $D$'s conjugacy class always the identity?  Of course not.

Comment: @Arthur the issue is I never claimed $D$ couldn't be diagonal though Ben seemed to suggest I did.  So he didn't ask "why a claim of [mine] is true", he asked why something I didn't say is true.  I happen to like Ben's postings so my suspicion is that a more careful read of the argument would have prevented this.

Comment: @user8675309 Here is my main issue with the phrasing of your first comment: when you say "Then $AB=BA$ implies $B$ must be diagonal which is a contradiciton" How is $B$ being diagonal a contradiction? Why is it impossible for $B$ to be diagonal? What does it contradict? This is what I am asking about, and as far as I can tell it is also what Ben is asking about.

Comment: @Arthur *"Why is it impossible for  to be diagonal?"* -- I addressed this two comments up where I highlighted the difference between "**can** be diagonal" and "**must** be diagonal".  Perhaps I should have bolded "must" in my original comment. The reality is this question is basic and shows no effort at a solution by OP -- i.e. community guidelines preclude one from giving a full answer.  I tried for a middle ground -- answering the question in a terse way that would (hopefully) prompt OP to put in effort to connect several dots.  I did not anticipate superusers struggling with the dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example, consider the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}, \quad B = \pmatrix{3&1\\0&4}, \quad P = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}, \quad D = \pmatrix{3&0\\0&4}.
$$
It holds that $AD = DA$, but $AB \neq BA$.